# How to use ssh-add to remove identities (pem files) from the agent

Tags: linux, ssh, pem, ssh-agent

I can add pem files to my SSH agent very easily using `ssh-add`, like so:

```
$ ssh-add /home/jsmith/keys/mytest.pem
```

But I can't seem to remove them:

```
$ ssh-add -d /home/jsmith/keys/mytest.pem
Bad key file /home/jsmith/keys/mytest.pem: No such file or directory
```

The pem file still exists though... I haven't moved or changed it in any way.  Why am I having so much trouble removing this pem file from my SSH agent that I just added a moment ago?  What's the correct way to do this?

I want to **avoid** using `ssh-add -D` (with a capital "D") because that would delete all of the identities from my SSH agent, and I only want to delete the one I've specified.

Comment: On what system?

Comment: Linux (it's in the title of the question)

Comment: Please add a linux tag.

Comment: Did you already check out this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361531/55352 ?

Comment: I think you just linked to this same page?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to use the public key for this. So first extract the public key and then remove it from the agent.

```
ssh-keygen -y -f /home/jsmith/keys/mytest.pem > /home/jsmith/keys/mytest.pub
ssh-add -d /home/jsmith/keys/mytest.pub
```

The man page mentions the "public" key as well: "if no public key is found at a given path, ssh-add will append .pub and retry".

Comment: Thank you, this works!  Though it seems very convoluted - is there really no way to just delete the pem file from your ssh keychain without jumping through hoops like this?

Comment: The technical answer is that the [command sent to an ssh agent to remove a key](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-miller-ssh-agent-01.html#rfc.section.4.3) identifies a key by its public portion. It's possible to derive the public portion of a key from the contents of a private key file, but apparently the ssh-add program doesn't contain logic to do that when deleting a key.

Comment: Is this correct? The man page says `-d` is : `       -d     Debug mode.  When this option is 
specified ssh-agent will not fork and will writ
e debug information to standard error`?

Comment: Man page for what? ssh-add? See https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add.

Comment: That's weird. Another man page say: *"-d Deletes the given identities from the agent. The **private** key files for the identities to be deleted should be listed on the command line."* Either way, the easiest way to drop the key in memory is to kill and restart the key-server.

Answer (score 4):

The best alternative I've found is to re-add the same file but with a life-time of 1 second:

```
ssh-add -t 1 myfile.pem
```

It is easier to remember than extracting the public key.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the comment associated with the key you can simply get the public key from the agent and pipe it back in to delete it.

```
ssh-add -L | grep -F 'test@example.com' | ssh-add -d -
```